# ImportError: cannot import name Publisher

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I succesfully created an executable version (Py2exe, Pyinstaller) of my application. When I try to run the app from .exe, I get an error as follows in the log file:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "CreateAS.pyw", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Publisher`

I am really stuck in this part. Could you help me out?

Thanks

Comment: The [NoSectionError](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.NoSectionError) exception is raised when a section is not found. Have you confirmed that you do have a section called `locations`?

Comment: I solved this issue by integrating pulp-related code into my main .pyw module. So there is only one python module now. But this time I get a new error as explained above.

Comment: Please describe how you imported ``Publisher`` from ``CreateAS.pyw``, where is ``Publisher`` located and what's its use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using a version of [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org) that is `>= 2.8.11.0`? If so, the `wx.lib.pubsub` package has changed. [This page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) describes the changes. There is also a thread on the [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org) mailing list [here](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/browse_thread/thread/d448a42abdae3e69/318cc65f2b54348f) that talks about this.

To make this all work in my project, I did the following described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/msg/03dbfca87bee4830) which was part of the above mailing list thread. I summarize below:

> The much preferable alternative (ie no
>   hacks!) if you can hack it (sorry!) 
>   is to use the same messaging protocol
>   as v1, but in latest API, this is 
>   called "arg1":
>
> ```
> # only in app's startup  module   
> from wx.lib.pubsub import setuparg1   
> # in all modules that use pubsub 
> from wx.lib.pubsub import pub as Publisher
> ```
>
> and replace any occurence of `"Publisher()." by "Publisher."`

Then in my `setup.py` script, I had to add the following to the options:

```
options = {
    "py2exe": {"packages": ['wx.lib.pubsub']}
}
setup(data_files=data_files,
      windows=[
              {'script': 'btpos.py'],
               options=options)
```

You should now be able to build an executable using the new version of pubsub, but with the old api. You might also want to check out the new v3 api of pubsub. If your project isn't too big, you can probably get by without changing too much.

Comment: Importing Publisher after setuparg1 doesn't work, whereas trying it with setupv1 it does. However, in both cases when compiling I still get the ImportError.

Answer (score 5):

try like this:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import setuparg1
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub as Publisher
```

Then: replace any occurence of`Publisher()`by`Publisher.`

Comment: This answer does not provide anything new over the accepted answer, also this is a more than three year old question.

Answer (score 2):

I was using an example code that used wx.lib.pubsub to study from and came across this problem too.

To fix this issue simply, I just changed the line:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub
```

To:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
```

The accepted answers has links that still make it right, but for simplicity, I've added this solution because the accepted solution was a little confusing.

Comment: This was the shortest way to get a old program running quickly!