# py2exe Import Error

Tags: wxpython

I successfully created a .exe from my .py using py2exe. But when I try to run the app from the exe I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "StreetSoccer.py", line 13, in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import name Publisher
```

I alredy found this page: [ImportError: cannot import name Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374451/importerror-cannot-import-name-publisher) but I'm using python2.7.
Here is the line of my .py where I import Publisher:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher
```

Hope you can help me.

---

Edit:
I made these changes:

```
# from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupv1
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
Publisher = pub.Publisher()
```

And now I get this error message (after py2exe):

```
File "StreetSoccer.py", line 14, in <module>
File "wx\lib\pubsub\setupv1.pyc", line 16, in setVersion
File "wx\lib\pubsub\pubsubconf.pyc", line 16, in setVersion
File "wx\lib\pubsub\pubsubconf.pyc", line 70, in setVersion
File "wx\lib\pubsub\pubsubconf.pyc", line 78, in __setupForV1
File "wx\lib\pubsub\pub.pyc", line 24, in <module>
File "wx\lib\pubsub\core\listener.pyc", line 13, in <module>
Import Error: No module named listenerimpl
```

Answer (score 1):

py2exe does not include all packages you use, like in this case the packages related to pubsub. Use a `setup.py` that tells py2exe about the relevant pubsub packages:

```
setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    windows=[{'script': 'StreetSoccer.py'}],
    options=[{'includes': ["wx.lib.pubsub.*", "wx.lib.pubsub.core.*", 
                           "wx.lib.pubsub.core.kwargs.*"]}]
)
```

See also: [ImportError: cannot import name Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374451/importerror-cannot-import-name-publisher)