# How to Use py2exe on GUI Made in wxPython with Custom Modules using __import__()

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, py2exe

I've made a GUI that runs beautifully in Python, but want to make an exe so I can give it to people who do not have Python.  I've created exe's before using `py2exe`, but never with a GUI.  As with any other first time, I ran into some issues which I've managed to fix except one; when I run the executable, a blank window pops up which looks like a cmd prompt, then disappears after a few seconds.  After closer inspection, I found an error message which pops up right before the window disappears. Its an `ImportError` saying it cannot find a file I created and then imported using `name = __import__("CRPYLog")` where `CRPYLog` is the name of the file it cannot find.

I've tried placing this file in the same directory as the executable and because of limitations with `__import__()` I can't specify a path of the file.  My problem seems identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253048/py2exe-import-error), except I'm using `__import__()`.  How do I adapt that solution for `__import__()`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the name of the module, why are you using `__import__` instead of just doing `import CRPYLog`?

Comment: Because I borrowed it from an old program of mine that had a variable name instead.  When I switch it over to ```import``` it works perfectly..... Boy, this is embarrassing! Well, thanks!